# React. Подъем состояния

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вопрос на засыпку. Возможен ли подъем состояния в функциональных компонентах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос про то что может ли дочерний компонент передавать данные родительскому, то ответ - да, может. Обычно это делается через функции обратного вызова

```
const ChildrenComponent = () => {
  return <input onChange={handleSomeEvent} />;
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const handleSomeEvent = event => {
    console.log(event);
  };

  return <ChildrenComponent onChange={handleSomeEvent}></ChildrenComponent>;
}
```